# How to Stop Timer on Mouse Click when using Web Browser in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, timer, webkit

I have created a Windows form in which i have added `WebKit Browser`. I have created a timer which sends user to `'PlayVideo' Form` after every 5 seconds. 
I want the timer to stop and start again if user clicks on the form.
The problem i am facing is that it is not detecting form clicks. If i remove WebKit Browser from FORM it detects Form Clicks and reset timer.
Kindly tell me a way to detect mouse clicks on WebKitBrowser.

```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoplayer videoplayer = new videoplayer();
        videoplayer.Show();

        this.Hide();

        timer1.Stop();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();

    }

    private void Form1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();

        timer1.Start();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need some form-wide mouse event. In fact you can handle the `DoubleClick` event of the `WebBrowser` instead, however I've tried it and that event (and some other mouse events) is not supported. So you can try implementing the following form-wide mouse event handler with the help of `IMessageFilter`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }
    //...
    //method implementation of the interface IMessageFilter
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        //WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203
        if (m.Msg == 0x203) {
            //your code goes here...
            timer1.Stop();
            timer1.Start();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```